# Object showing behind transparent gradient

Tags: inkscape, transparency, gradient, stroke

I want to draw objects that have a transparent radial gradient in the stroke paint option.

The problem I have is that I can still see the object behind because of the radial gradient. How make the bottom object not visible when another is placed on top of it?

Comment: I assume you can see the object behind because your gradient is transparent? Can't you just use a non-transparent gradient? (Or maybe I'm misunderstanding... adding a screenshot of the issue may help)

Comment: That's right, it is because of the transparent gradient. I would like that the gradient stays, can this be possible?

Comment: If you don't want to see what's behind the gradient why does it need to be transparent?

Answer (score 2):

Add a copy of the shape below. Color it with the wanted non-transparent backcround color- for example fill it with solid white and select that also for the strokes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the transparency of your gradient and add objects below / behind it you have two options:

- **make the gradient opaque**: use a color that matches the background instead of a transparent color. This way your gradient will still look the same but any objects behind it will not show through.
- **use an opacity mask on the object behind**: this way your gradient object can stay transparent and the object behind will not be visible. It's more work because you have to add the mask to the any objects you add behind your gradient (I'm not familiar with Inkscape in particular so correct me if I'm wrong)